# How can a set a Security Group's email address using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, g-suite, groups

I need to create many groups with email addresses. I would prefer to use Security Groups to reduce the number of groups we have to maintain, otherwise we'd have an identical Distribution Group for every one of these Security Groups.

We're using the groups for Google Apps, not Exchange. All I'm finding are Exchange solutions, and I'm not sure installing Exchange related tools and using the `Mail-Enable` command (etc) is the right way to go.

I can see via the GUI that input in the E-mail field sets the `mail` property, but I can't seem to figure out how I can set it using PowerShell. I would've thought this would work:

```
$group.mail = $email
Set-ADGroup $group
```

But no luck.

How can I set the `mail` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Set-ADGroup "SecurityGroupName" -Replace @{mail="test@example.com"}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Enable-DistributionGroup -Identity 'acquisitions email' -Alias 'acquisitions-email'
```

The first answer given for this question applies an email address but doesn't provide any MSExchange attributes that are required for an accurate email address.

Comment: Did you read the question or just the title? It's not for Exchange.